# HTACCESS Password protecting a specific URL

Tags: .htaccess

I am using .htaccess to rewrite URL's, so the url for

```
 www.mypages.com/home
```

would map to

```
 www.mypages.com/index.php?page=home
```

I have the url

```
 www.mypages.com/secure
```

that I wish to protect using standard .htaccess password protection, is there anyway I can secure just this page?

Thanks in advance

John